# What function in R can I use to transfer data from one matrix to another using conditionals?

Tags: r

I have a matrix with well over 200 columns and only 2 rows. And I intend to separate this matrix into 4 different categories depending on what category each column identifies with. How would I do this using conditionals or is there any other way?
For example, I was thinking of first identifying each category. Which would cat1 <- (matrix.name[“first row name”, i(to go in place for every column]) == “A” & matrix.name[“second row name”, i(to go in place for every column]) == “B”)
How would i go about using cat1 to print in a new matrix?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and its expected output

Comment: How is JavaScript or Python or RStudio relevant?

Comment: @VLAZ the code is to be done on R

Comment: Which suggests that neither JavaScript, nor Python, nor RStudio are relevant. Why are they added as tags?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
some_mtx <- matrix(c(rep('A', 10), rep('C',10), rep('B', 10), rep('D',10)), ncol = 20, byrow=TRUE)
some_mtx
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
[1,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"   "C"   "C"   "C"   "C"  
[2,] "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"  "B"   "D"   "D"   "D"   "D"  
     [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,] "C"   "C"   "C"   "C"   "C"   "C"  
[2,] "D"   "D"   "D"   "D"   "D"   "D"  

matrix(c(some_mtx[which(some_mtx =='A')], some_mtx[which(some_mtx == 'D')]), ncol = 10)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "D"  "D"  "D"  "D"  "D"  
[2,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "D"  "D"  "D"  "D"  "D"  

# or with `byrow=TRUE`
matrix(c(some_mtx[which(some_mtx =='A')], some_mtx[which(some_mtx == 'D')]), ncol = 10, byrow = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A"  
[2,] "D"  "D"  "D"  "D"  "D"  "D"  "D"  "D"  "D"  "D"
```

Imagining your data object.